# Steps into trouble shooting DHCP on Windows

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

We are trying to setup a DHCP Server Client to listen to requests on a specific Ethernet line.

We had IT open the firewall ports for the port 67, and 68. Then using a DHCP Client we've successfully used on Windows before, we should be seeing a client request across the network.

In terms of debugging this, what could be the cause?

Firewall? Another process blocking the port? Is there another layer to be checking?

Comment: Are you trying to setup a server or a client? “DHCP Server Client” is an oxymoron. Clients don’t listen for requests.

Comment: sorry! Setup a server.. good point.. @Appleoddity

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify that. You reference client and/or server a couple of times.